# What is correct heading setup for subpages

Tags: seo, html

What is the best for seo of the following:

1. using `<h1>keyword</h1>` in layout and putting each subpage title in `</h2>`
2. using `<h1>keyword</h1>` only for main page and on each subpage replace it to `<h2>keyword</h2>` and using `h1` tags for subapge title
3. not using `<h1>keyword</h1>` on any of the pages instead put keyword in

   in header and use  for each subpage and using `<h1>keyword + something for main page title</h1>`
4. None of the above (please go into as much details)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(4.) Use an `h1` heading that properly reflects the content of the page (not site). Anything else is trickery that may fool some search engines some of the time but is usually just waste of time and spoils the page.

The `h1` markup simply indicates the content as the top-level heading of the page, and search engines normally assign a large relative weight to it. But it is just relative to the page content as a whole.

Comment: Can you please explain further in what tags and where should Site title/logo be put?

Comment: If the site has a title, it typically appears in a block of its own above navigation and heading. The same applies to a logo, though a logo could be placed more freely as it is typically short. There is no need to do magic things about them in an effort to affect search engines.